# PHP: Using globally defined closure in a class method

Tags: php, class, closures, global

I have a closure that is a `global` variable and I would like to run it in a class I made. However, when I try the following code, I get the error, `Exception: Call to undefined method TestClass::globalFunction()`.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$globalFunction = function($var){
    echo "works $var";
};

class TestClass{
    private $globalFunction;
    function __construct(){
        $this->globalFunction = $GLOBALS['globalFunction'];
    }
    function testFunc(){
        $this->globalFunction('a');
    }
}
$arr = new TestClass();
$arr->testFunc();
```

Comment: It's not really related to it being global. Only problem is the syntax of calling it.

Comment: Have you considered using a trait for this? It seems like it might be a good fit.

Comment: I hadn't seen traits before. That is an interesting option, certainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$this->globalfunction` is a variable, not a method, you need to wrap it in parentheses to force PHP to evaluate `$this->globalfunction` *before* attempting to call it as a function i.e.

```
function testFunc(){
    ($this->globalFunction)('a');
}
```

Output:

```
works a
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9X7uq)